# Scala equivalent of .NET's Task.Factory.StartNew?

Tags: scala, task

In C# you can write:

```
var alphaTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<alpha>(() =>
{
    return someWork(n);<br>
});
// ... do some other work, and later get the result from the task<br>
var res = alphaTask.Result;
```

How would this simple construction look like in Scala?
Thank you.

Comment: A note on stackoverflow use.  If you feel this answer to be correct (and, well, it is), then you should mark it as such

Answer (score 10):

In Scala 2.8, the simplest equivalent would be

```
val future = Futures.future{
                someWork(n)
           }
// ... do some other work, and later get the result from the task
val res = future();
```